# jest could not locate module by using main entry point

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have an issue where my compiled code works fine in the browser, but jest throws an error.
The error appears when importing like this

```
import { Button } from '@pipe-dream/core'
```

However, using an explicit path to the main entry solves it:

```
import { Button } from '@pipe-dream/core/dist/pipe-dream.js'
```

That is strange because the `package.json` in `@pipe-dream/core` already specifies the key: `"main": "/dist/pipe-dream.js"` - so it should yield the same results?

The error:

> ● Test suite failed to run
>
> ```
> Configuration error:
>
> Could not locate module @pipe-dream/core mapped as:
> /Users/anders/Code/my-project/node_modules/@pipe-dream/core.
>
> Please check your configuration for these entries:
> {
>   "moduleNameMapper": {
>     "/^@pipe-dream\/(.*)$/": "/Users/anders/Code/my-project/node_modules/@pipe-dream/$1"
>   },
>   "resolver": null
> }
> ```

But looking through my node_modules it IS there. And why does it work when importing with explicit path to dist..

To see if there was something wrong with my syntax, I made a dummy package in `node_modules` and that seems to work, at least it did not generate the same error.
`dummy package.json`:

```
main: "/dist/index.js"
```

`/dist/index.js`:
    module.exports.dummy = function() {
        console.log("I can console log!");
    }

`usage`:

```
import { dummy } from '@anders/dummy'
dummy()
```

And that seems to work. Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test to edit the `main` key in `package.json` to not start with `'/'`. That might cause trouble for jest.

Example `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "@pipe-dream/core",
  "main": "dist/pipe-dream.js",
  ...
}
```